# Django: method in models vs method in views

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I ask myself this question, what the difference and the more performant between a method in models.py and views.py ?

*Example 1:*

**models.py:**

```
class Counter(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def add_one(self):
        self.number += 1
        self.save()
```

**views.py**

```
from *xxx* import Counter

def count(request):
    c = Counter()
    c.add_one()
    c.save()
    return render(request, *xxx*)
```

*Example 2:*

**models.py:**

```
class Counter(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
from *xxx* import Counter

def add_one(nb):
    nb += 1
    return nb

def count(request):
    c = Counter()
    c.number = add_one(c.number)
    return render(request, *xxx*)
```

My example is a little bit simple, but what the difference in the real life with big method and so many variables ?

Its have an impact on the performance of the server ? Did he have conventional or preference to choose one way ?

Comment: Why would there be any performance difference? Code is code, no matter where you put it.

Comment: The second one would be a lot faster since you never save it to the database, other than that they do the same exact thing

Comment: You can read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/performance/#get-things-right-from-the-start) you have different possibility and it's to work on differente level on the framework and it's faster or not. And i try to find the good way to optimise my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

both approaches are wrong!

The correct way is

```
Counter.objects.filter(pk=some_id).update(number=F('number')+1)
```

Note that this approach is needed to avoid race conditions. your current approach would need transactions to make it work properly. Code like the above typically go into the view.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the incrementation was a simple example, in practice i do many process very repetitive with many treatment in the input of the users before to save it in database. So i know update is better, but i find an example very easy.

Comment: In pratice "yes" you reply to my example. But the question was just more 
theoretical : `what the difference and the more performant between a method in models.py and views.py`, if i understand you say view approach is better.

Comment: still both your comments are irrelevent. Because the code you have posted is simply the wrong way to do it. I suggest you post another question but before you do. Please read: 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank ! you focus your answer to reply to my code example, but i can find some interesting informations in your message.

Comment: Glad it was usefull

Comment: I have to disagree on the "Code like the above typically go into the view" part - it really depends on what the effective code (not the dummy example provided by the OP) really do, how much of it is really domain model logic and as such should be encapsulated in the model etc. As far as I'm concerned I favor smart models and dumb views (the view should only handle the user->model interaction, not the model's inner logic).

Comment: hello @brunodesthuilliers I think we even agreed on something once.

Comment: @e4c5 well yes we did - I think I even upvoted some of your answers actually ;)

Comment: My question wasn't clear, but @e4c5 give me a good indication, and i read this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/performance/#get-things-right-from-the-start) because `Code is not just code` (or perhaps for beginners). I try to find the good way to realize a good code and the indication above finally strengthened me work work more on models to have better performance. Thank you.

Comment: yes, code is not just code for everyone. Realzing that means you are well on your way to success. All the best